# How to compare byte and char in Java?

Tags: java, char, compare, byte

I have a string with the server response. First letter is char 255 in ASCII code. I want to compare it. I was trying:

```
if ((byte)serverResponse.charAt(0) == (byte)0xff)
```

but the if "says" it's not equal.

Comment: did you print the value of `serverResponse.charAt(0)`?

Comment: Believe the "if"! You should print the value of `serverResponse.charAt(0)` and see.